# Copy row when cell contains "x" with another condition to meet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, row, move

[Spreadsheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBKvy.png)I have a script from one of the old topics to copy row when a certain value is in a cell:

```
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "Stock" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() <= 5) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() +1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

However, I need to make a thresholds for a categories. Let's say i have 2 categories in the stock: "Power Tools" and "Hand Tools". In case of Power tools i would like the script to run when the value reach 5 or less and in case of Hand Tools 10 or less. Category is set in column A and it have been set before so the trigger doesn't work when i write to conditions in the code as i changed only the amount value. Many thanks for advice!

Comment: Can you show what you're trying to do with a sample sheet? It's unclear what you mean by checking the category. Is column a the category such as Power Tools/Hand Tools or is the threshold (less than 5?)

Comment: I've added SS to original post